# How do I know where to redirect spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial)

[image]

where is the /login in the action?

where is processing this page?

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically by spring security starter, once you add spring security dependency spring boot will detect the existence of specified class in the class path which will be added once you have the spring security dependency, a bean will be created as well for it and this will be the default behavior.

check this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) for more details

Comment: thanks Amer!

I'm new in Spring, do you know about an excelent tutorial for this?
greetings.

Comment: Thanks Amer, i really apprecited it.